# Error message in R could not find function "get.current.chob"

Tags: r, function, quantmod, indicator

I am following code from a textbook called "Data Mining with R" and I've hit a stumbling block when trying to run the sample code myself.

Here is the code so far:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("^GSPC")

colnames(GSPC) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "AdjClose")

T.ind <- function(quotes, tgt.margin=.025, n.days=10) {

  v <- apply(HLC(quotes), 1, mean)
  r <- matrix(NA, ncol=n.days, nrow=NROW(quotes))

  for(x in 1:n.days) r[,x] <- Next(Delt(v,k=x), x)
  x <- apply(r,1, function(x) sum(x[x>tgt.margin|x < -tgt.margin]))

  if (is.xts(quotes))
    xts(x, time(quotes))
  else x

}

candleChart(last(GSPC, "1 year"), theme="white", TA=NULL)
avgPrice <- function(p) apply(HLC(p), 1, mean)
addAvgPrice <- newTA(FUN=avgPrice, col=1, legend="AvgPrice")
addT.ind <- newTA(FUN=T.ind, col="red", legend="tgtRet")
addAvgPrice(on=1)
addT.ind()
```

But for the last 2 lines I get the error message:

```
> addAvgPrice(on=1)
Error in addAvgPrice(on = 1) : could not find function "get.current.chob"
> addT.ind()
Error in addT.ind() : could not find function "get.current.chob"
```

What is additionally odd is that I ran the code on 1 machine & have no issues but on my main PC I keep getting the error.

I tried googling this error but could not find any real solutions or explanations.

Any insight or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into R and I didn't get any error messages. I'm running R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit). With "quantmod_0.4-0 TTR_0.22-0", "xts_0.9-7", and "zoo_1.7-11"

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the confirmation. I have the same package versions & tried on both R Studio & R, restarted the PC, cleared the environment but still getting same error message. May need to test another PC.

Comment: How did you confirm the versions? Did you run `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: This has been fixed in quantmod_0.4-2 on CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

```
> get.current.chob
Error: object 'get.current.chob' not found
```

get.current.chob is in quantmod, so...

```
> quantmod:::get.current.chob
function () 
{
    first.chob <- which(sapply(sys.frames(), function(x) exists("chob", 
        envir = x)))[1]
    if (!is.na(first.chob)) {
        lchob <- get("chob", envir = first.chob)
    }
    else {
        gchob <- get.chob()
        if (dev.cur() == 1 || length(gchob) < dev.cur()) 
            stop("improperly set or missing graphics device")
        current.chob <- which(sapply(gchob, function(x) {
            ifelse(class(x) == "chob" && x@device == as.numeric(dev.cur()), 
                TRUE, FALSE)
        }))
        if (identical(current.chob, integer(0))) 
            stop("no current plot")
        lchob <- gchob[[current.chob]]
    }
    return(lchob)
}
<environment: namespace:quantmod>
```